# Доступ к this в анонимном классе

Tags: java

Внутри реализации метода нужен доступ к this! Как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
for (int i = 0; i < h.getWidgetCount(); i++) {
                ((CommonTextBox) ((VerticalPanel) h.getWidget(i)).getWidget(1)).addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent keyUpEvent) {
                        consoleOut("" + ((CommonTextBox) __this???__ ).getText());
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: @evm: А чем вас предложенный не устраивает?

Comment: @DreamChild, @VladD зачем, если есть нормальный способ "из коробки" ?

Comment: Нормальный вопрос зачем минусовать? Автор просто немного неверно сформулировал его. Исправил формулировку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так: Имя_Внешнего_класса.this.метод_внешнего_класса.
Например:

```
MainActivity.this.method();
```

Answer (score 0):

Скопируйте ссылку на this в локальную переменную и пользуйтесь этой переменной изнутри метода, не забыв при этом добавить модификатор final.